# Python range to list

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a range to list.

```
nums = []
for x in range (9000, 9004):
    nums.append(x)
    print nums
```

output

```
[9000]
[9000, 9001]
[9000, 9001, 9002]
[9000, 9001, 9002, 9003]
```

I just need something like

```
 [9000, 9001, 9002, 9003]
```

How do I get just the requred list ?

Comment: print outside the loop

Comment: get rid of the print statement . Also, no need of the loop. You can just cast the range into a list.

Comment: Thanks - Print outside the loop helped.

Comment: The fundamental misunderstanding here is that "getting a result from the code" and "making something appear on the screen" are two **completely different** tasks that have **absolutely nothing to do with each other**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are taking the print statement under the for loop, so just placed the print statement out of the loop.

```py
nums = []
for x in range (9000, 9004):
    nums.append(x)
print (nums)
```

Answer (score 35):

You can just assign the range to a variable:

```
range(10)
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In your case:

```
>>> nums = range(9000,9004)
>>> nums
[9000, 9001, 9002, 9003]
>>>
```

However, in `python3` you need to qualify it with a list()

```
>>> nums = list(range(9000,9004))
>>> nums
[9000, 9001, 9002, 9003]
>>>
```

Comment: I think that may only apply to Python2, so you might want to qualify. Cheers :)

Comment: wonder what is the difference between this and `l = [i for i in range(9000,9004)`

Comment: @letsc doesn't that make a list, then makes a copy of that list, then throws the first list away?

Comment: @letsc in python 3, range is a generator so its essentially the same as calling `list` since all that `list` does is exhause `next(iterator)` and keep on appending to a list.

Answer (score 13):

## Python 3

For efficiency reasons, Python no longer creates a list when you use `range`.  The new range is  like `xrange` from Python 2.7.  It creates an iterable range object that you can loop over or access using `[index]`.

If we combine this with the positional-expansion operator `*`, we can easily generate lists despite the new implementation.

```
[*range(9000,9004)]
```

## Python 2

In Python 2, `range` does create a list... so:

```
range(9000,9004)
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of range is a list:

```
>>> print range(9000, 9004)
[9000, 9001, 9002, 9003]
```

Comment: I believe this depends on the Python version. Python2 outputs a list (`xrange` is for lazy generators), Py3 outputs a generator.